# Play-slick postgres evolution for create function

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-slick

Here's my evolution 1.sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_changetimestamp_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.changetimestamp = now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

But when I apply this evolution, play-slick is giving me this error

```
we got the following error: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN NEW.changetimestamp = now()" Position: 79 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601], while trying to run this SQL script:
```

Any idea what's going on? I could create that function on postgres console directly

Answer (score 1):

Hi Steve did you solve your issue?

If you check Play's manual about evolutions you will find the following:

> Play splits your .sql files into a series of semicolon-delimited
>   statements before executing them one-by-one against the database. So
>   if you need to use a semicolon within a statement, escape it by
>   entering ;; instead of ;. For example, `INSERT INTO punctuation(name,
>   character) VALUES ('semicolon', ';;');`.

Your script should be modified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_changetimestamp_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.changetimestamp = now();;
  RETURN NEW;;
END;;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```